# KVM wireless bridged networking mode not operational

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge, wifi

Why does KVM not support wireless bridge networking mode, whereas VirtualBox and do it very well? `parprouted` doesn't help.

I want to allow KVM guests to act as if they have a bridged network interface rather then NAT. As it turns out you can not simply bridge your wireless card with `brctl` as you do with a wired NIC.

Comment: Huh? Could you provide details as to why you're saying this?

Answer (score 0):

Because [802.11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.11) looks just enough like [Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) to make you think that it is Ethernet, whereas it's really not. Things like [bridging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_%28networking%29) don't Just Work with 802.11, which is why putting a wireless interface into a [`brctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/brctl) bridge doesn't work as expected. VirtualBox and VMware have implemented specific wireless bridging in order to make this work (they just don't make a distinction to users).

The solution is to use [`parprouted`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/parprouted), which essentially bridges at layer 3 instead of layer 2. The caveat is that this only works for unicast traffic -- broadcast traffic is not relayed across the bridge. This is a problem for DHCP, which requires broadcast. If the VM needs to DHCP across the bridge, you need to setup [`dhcrelay`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dhcrelay) as well in order to get this working.